# Scroll Form with page scrolling and add form on slider

Tags: forms

On my Wordpress Theme i want to add a contact form which should be display on slider on right side so that when user scrolls the page the form must be scroll with the page.

How to achieve this functionality? Is there any plugin available for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to achieve "sticky" effect. This might help you do this.

[My Sticky Sidebar Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mystickysidebar/)